# Append from own object

Tags: jquery

how can I just append an object to another in the same object? Like this:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">Foo</div>
  <div class="lorem">Bar</div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">Foo</div>
  <div class="lorem">Bar</div>
</div>
```

Now i will but the first div into the second one, so like:

```
$('.bar').appendTo('.lorem');
```

Here the Foo will appear on every bar on the website. In this example it will appear twice ([like this](http://codepen.io/Sukrams/pen/zqGeyB)). Is there a possibility to jump just the Foo into the .lorem-div which is in the same container?

I tried it with something like `$(this).$('.bar').appendTo(this).('.lorem')` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to iterate over the elements with class `bar` and append it to its adjacent sibling element by using `next()`. And the important point is that `.next()` has to be invoked over `$(this)`,

```
$('.bar').each(function(){
  $(this).appendTo($(this).next(".lorem"))
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aq28czsa/)